# side channel attacks against TDES (compared to AES)

Tags: aes, 3des, side-channel-attack

We all know AES has some pretty strong side channel attacks, some where (with a couple of hundred know plain- and ciphertext combinations) a key can be derived in a matter of minutes. Others may take a bit longer but they are out there if people have full access to the hardware and control over the algorithm.

Does TDES also have those devastating side channel attacks? I'm delving into the security of both TDES and AES and am a bit biased when it comes to TDES since well.. it's stitched together to give DES a longer life span, and to me that's not proper security. But I cannot find as many (good) attacks against TDES as i can find them for AES.

**my question is:**
 
Does TDES have the same vulnerabilities as AES, especially when it comes to side channel attacks?

*P.S.

I do realize there are more attacks and papers published for AES since AES is more of a popular topic then TDES.*

Comment: I don't think the AES side-channels are as big as you think. If you're referring to DJB's paper, he used a very precise timer on the server to attack AES.

Comment: No i'm referring to a demonstration by a french guy (who hardly spoke english) he showed us in real time he could get the first few bytes from a key we (as an audience) created, he left it running through the seminar and it ended up recovering the whole key. this used electromagnetic emissions and plaintext + corresponding ciphertext to get it. though he did make clear the same could be done without knowing either the plain or cipher text and the time that would take wasn't much longer than what he showed us.

Comment: So it wasn't just a timing attack, but a power analysis attack? In that case you're pretty much doomed with any general purpose CPU. If you want to prevent attacks where the attacker has physical access to the device, you should use special purpose hardware designed to make these attacks harder. The choice of cipher matters far less compared to how much effort the hardware designer put into preventing those attacks.

Comment: Search for DES (differential) power analysis, you'll see tons of papers, including [Paul Kocher's](http://www.cryptography.com/public/pdf/DPA.pdf#page=4) (he was the first to come out with the technique), and this [intro](http://www.cryptography.com/public/pdf/DPATechInfo.pdf) from the company he founded, basically around solving that problem.